# Jquery ajaxError handler on iframe not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I am working on application that has an iframe document in the main window. This iframe is from another library within the same company but is owned by another team, therefore cannot make any changes to it in a short timeframe (shared component/library).

So, as temporary solution, I am adding code from our codebase which is the main window, that will listen to the iframe events and respond accordingly. First thing I needed was to be able to add an `ajaxError` handler (https://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/) in the iframe which uses jQuery for all its XHR calls hence I should be able to listen to ajax errors.

This is my code:

```
const iframeEl = document.querySelector('.child-iframe'); 
$(iframeEl) //tried both with iframeEl.contentWindow and iframeEl.contentWindow.document
    .on(
            'ajaxError',
            (event, jqxhr, settings, thrownError) => console.log(event)
    );
```

I am executing the above code AFTER the iframe has loaded the html document in its src attribute (I can confirm this and have excluded the code for iframe load listener), however this `ajaxError` handler is never being called.

Can someone please let me know what is wrong with the code above?

Comment: I think you need to bind the event handler to the `.contentWindow` of the iframe.

Comment: Try `$(document.querySelector('.child-iframe').contentWindow).on.(...)`

Comment: @Barmar - I have tried both .contentWindow and .contentWindow.document, will update the question to mention that

Answer (score -1):

Finally managed to find the solution.

The tricky part is making sure that you add the jQuery ajaxError on the iframe and not the jQuery of the parent window.

Yes - there are 2 jQuery instances, 1 for each window & document object:

1. parent window & document object
2. iframe window & document object

This is what worked for me:

```
const iframeEl = document.querySelector('.child-iframe'); 
iframeEl.contentWindow.jQuery(iframeEl.contentWindow.document) // this is the important bit, you need to access the iframe's jQuery
.on(
            'ajaxError',
            (event, jqxhr, settings, thrownError) => console.log(event)
    );
```